# How to display all records to update form in Yii

Tags: yii

I have one table and it's model. I have applied CRUD operation on that model.

But, but the issue is that: I want to display all records in one html page at once. And want to update any of the record from that table and when I submit the form, that records which are changed should be updated to the table.

[image: image for multiple record editing]

In the above image there's 3 records from the table price_list, along with its price and the field to show price of car or not.

**I want to update multiple records using single form and even if possible I want to add new record at last from the same page.**

Is this possible in Yii framework ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty common task working with yii, and actually is not as complicated as it may seems.  Here is all you need to know: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

It is really clear and converts perfectly your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Updating multiple records would be a case of passing an array of primary keys to [updateByPk()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateByPk-detail) or perhaps (if i understand this method correctly) [updateAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail) where new value different from old value.

Not to sure about inserting I'd think it would (programatically) have to be slightly separate from the update but I imagine can be done so the user can just edit the table and click save to save all there changes.

So in short yes but it looks to be something you'll have to implement. For reference [Yii's ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar) introductory documentation.